# Campo Number(3,0) em banco Oracle para Java

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring, jpa

Eu tenho uma tabela em um banco de dados Oracle 11g com um campo do tipo `NUMBER(3,0)`

Em um projeto Spring, possuo o seguinte repository:

```
@Repository
public interface TipoPropriRepository extends JpaRepository<TipoPropri, Byte> {
}
```

Que pertence a esta classe que foi **autogerada** pelo IntelliJ:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TIPOPROPRI")
public class TipoPropri {

    private byte cdTpPropr;

    @Id
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "CD_TP_PROPR")
    public byte getCdTpPropr() {
        return cdTpPropr;
    }

    public void setCdTpPropr(byte cdTpPropr) {
        this.cdTpPropr = cdTpPropr;
    }
}
```

Na minha classe `@Service` tenho o seguinte código:

```
@Service
 public class TipoProprService {

            @Autowired
            TipoPropriRepository tipoPropriRepository;

            public TipoPropri findById(byte id){
                Optional<TipoPropri> tipoPropri = tipoPropriRepository.findById(id);
                if (tipoPropri.isPresent()){
                    return tipoPropri.get();
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
    }
```

Mas quando chamo o método findById do meu Service com o seguinte código:

```
 tipoProprService.findById( (byte) Integer.parseInt("6") )
```

(O número 6 é uma String de exemplo de número que virá de uma parte do front end como variável)

Dá a seguinte exceção:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Overflow Numérico
at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.throwOverflow(NumberCommonAccessor.java:4170) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.getShort(NumberCommonAccessor.java:311) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedStatement.getShort(GeneratedStatement.java:305) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getShort(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:879) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
```

Eu tentei vários tipos de variávies no java, como Short, Long, Integer e sempre dá a mesma exceção. Eu não sei mais o que fazer.

Comment: `Byte` na declaração da interface e no `findById` de fato não cabe. Com `Short` deveria caber.

Comment: Ah, o corpo do seu método `findById` pode ser substituído para simplesmente `return tipoPropriRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);`.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver.

Na pergunta eu não coloquei os outros campos que tem na classe para a pergunta não ficar muito longa.

Mas essa classe tinha outros campos do tipo Short e Byte. **Eu mudei TODOS para `BIGDECIMAL`**, aí funcionou.